# How to decrypt enigma with 2 custom rotors and no reflector?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, sage

TL;DR: So for a homework assignment in our cryptography class we need to essentially write a script to decrypt given ciphertext from an Enigma machine with two given rotors, no reflector and a key.

### The Assignment

**Alphabet** is the usual English alphabet [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z].

**Rotors**

λ<sub>1</sub>=[8, 13, 24, 18, 9, 0, 7, 14, 10, 11, 19, 25, 4, 17, 12, 21, 15, 3, 22, 2, 20, 16, 23, 1, 6, 5] and

λ<sub>2</sub>=[10, 2, 21, 18, 23, 6, 16, 14, 8, 11, 1, 25, 15, 20, 0, 24, 17, 19, 22, 5, 4, 3, 9, 12, 13, 7]

**Key** K=<1, 13>

**Ciphertext**: XKWOU YTDLZ ZIFCY DBRWS FLGXV 
DUDNA KOFJA QHRKM NZWTY PZIJS... (Won't paste all the ciphertext as plaintext might not have been in English anyway).

---

### What I have tried

From my understanding, given rotors *λ<sub>1</sub>* and *λ<sub>2</sub>* a *i*-th plaintext letter *p<sub>i</sub>* is encrypted to

*c<sub>i</sub>= ρ<sup>-m<sub>2</sub></sup> λ<sub>2</sub> ρ<sup>m<sub>2</sub></sup> ρ<sup>-m<sub>1</sub></sup> λ<sub>1</sub> ρ<sup>m<sub>1</sub></sup> (p<sub>i</sub>)*

So decryption would be the opposite
*p<sub>i</sub>= ρ<sup>-m<sub>1</sub></sup> λ<sub>1</sub><sup>-1</sup> ρ<sup>m<sub>1</sub></sup> ρ<sup>-m<sub>2</sub></sup> λ<sub>2</sub><sup>-1</sup> ρ<sup>m<sub>2</sub></sup> (c<sub>i</sub>)*

**Where**

***i*** is letter index from rotor position *<0, 0>*

***m<sub>1</sub>***, ***m<sub>2</sub>*** are such that ***i = m<sub>1</sub> + 26 m<sub>2</sub> + ...*** (if *i = 9 = 9 + 26 * 0*, then *m<sub>1</sub> = 9, m<sub>2</sub> = 0*, if *i = 37 = 11 + 26 * 1*, then *m<sub>1</sub> = 11, m<sub>2</sub> = 1*)

***ρ<sup>α</sup>(t)*** is a rotation function ***ρ<sup>α</sup>(t) = t + α (mod 26)***

***λ(t)*** is given rotor permutation ***λ(t)=λ[t]*** (for instance *λ<sub>1</sub>('e')=λ<sub>1</sub>[4]=9*).

***λ(t)<sup>-1</sup>*** is opposite rotor permutation such that ***λ λ<sup>-1</sup>(t) = t*** (if *λ<sub>1</sub>(4)=9, then λ<sub>1</sub><sup>-1</sup>(9)=4*)

---

### Code part

This is the script I tried to write in Sage:

```
alphabet='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
rotor_1  = [8, 13, 24, 18, 9, 0, 7, 14, 10, 11, 19, 25, 4, 17, 12, 21, 15, 3, 22, 2, 20, 16, 23, 1, 6, 5]
rotor_2  = [10, 2, 21, 18, 23, 6, 16, 14, 8, 11, 1, 25, 15, 20, 0, 24, 17, 19, 22, 5, 4, 3, 9, 12, 13, 7]
cText = 'XKWOU YTDLZ ZIFCY DBRWS FLGXV DUDNA KOFJA QHRKM NZWTY PZIJS'
key = [1, 13]

def oppositeRot(rot):
    l=len(rot)
    oppositeRot=[0]*l
    for i in range(0,l):
        oppositeRot[rot[i]]=i
    return oppositeRot

def rotate(t, a):
    return alphabet[(alphabet.index(t) + a ) % len(alphabet)]

def rotor(t, rot):
    return alphabet[(alphabet.index(t) + rot[alphabet.index(t)]) % len(alphabet)]

def decipher(ciphertext, rot1, rot2, key):
    oppRot1 = oppositeRot(rot1)
    oppRot2 = oppositeRot(rot2)

    plaintext = "";
    m_1 = key[0]
    m_2 = key[1]
    for i in range (0, len(ciphertext)):
        if ciphertext[i] != ' ':
            c = alphabet[(alphabet.index(ciphertext[i]))] # c_i
            p = rotate(rotor(rotate(rotate(rotor(rotate(c, m_2), oppRot2), -m_2), m_1), oppRot1), -m_1) # p_i

            m_1 = (m_1 + 1) % len(oppRot1)

            if m_1 == 0:
                m_2 = (m_2 + 1) % len(oppRot2)

            plaintext += p
    return plaintext;

decipher(cText, rotor_1, rotor_2, key)
```

Any suggestions / ideas why this doesn't work? I've been at this for hours and can't seem to spot what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that assignment before ;).
Not sure what's wrong with your code, but you can inspect my solution.

```
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def numerify(text):
    res = []
    for letter in text:
        num = alphabet.index(letter)
        res.append(num)
    return res

def stringify(numbers):
    res = ''
    for number in numbers:
        letter = alphabet[number]
        res += letter
    return res

def rot(m, a):
    return (a+m) % len(alphabet)

def rsubst(rot, a):
    return rot.index(a)

def deEnigma(key, L1, L2, ciphertext):
    cipherVals = numerify(ciphertext)
    messageVals = []
    m1 = key[0]
    m2 = key[1]
    rIdx = 0

    for cipherVal in cipherVals:
        val = cipherVal
        val = rot(m2, val)
        val = rsubst(L2, val)
        val = rot(-m2, val)
        val = rot(m1, val)
        val = rsubst(L1, val)
        val = rot(-m1, val)

        m1 += 1
        rIdx += 1
        if (rIdx % len(alphabet)) == 0:
            m2 += 1

        messageVals.append(val)

    return stringify(messageVals)
```

Just put pass your variables into `deEnigma()`